# How do I force "batch prediction" to stop?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I tried tabular data training with the "Vertex AI" custom training.
I tried "batch prediction" with the model, but it didn't finish running.
According to the log, "too many 500 error responses" indicating that the prediction failed.

I tried to delete the batch prediction job from the console, but it remains in the running state.
I thought that the batch prediction job would stop if the model was deleted, and the model was deleted, but the batch prediction job was not deleted.

How do I force batch prediction to stop?

Comment: I thought the prediction process wasn't progressing at all, but a closer look at the logs shows that it is progressing, failing little by little.
But I want to know if there is a way to force stop.

Comment: The cause of the 500 error was that the source CSV file contained extra columns which were dropped during training.
(I tested with small data.)

Comment: I think you can raise it as a bug. Use "Send feedback" button in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/support/getting-support#file_bugs_or_feature_requests).

Comment: Thank you!
I will give feedback to support.

Answer (score 0):

I gave feedback to support.
Batch prediction completed naturally in 2 days.